# combinatorics circular arrangement problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If $n$ distinct things are arranged in a circle, then what are the number of ways selecting three of these things so that no two of them are next to each other?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566889/selection-in-circular-table/566929#566929) is the same, but for selecting $k$ rather than $3$. The question itself has the answer for $k=3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n\leq 5$, it is clear that it is impossible.

So let $n\geq 6$.
For the first object, there are $n$ possibilities.
Now 3 objects are forbidden (the chosen one and the distance 1 objects).
If as the second object you pick one of the 2 object in distance 2, for the last object there are $n-5$ possibilities. If as the second object you take one of the $n-5$ objects in distance $>2$, for the last objects there are $n - 6$ possibilities. So in total
$$
n\cdot (2(n-5) + (n-5)(n-6)) = n(n-5)(n-4)
$$
possibilities or, if you the order of the chosen object doesn't matter
$$
\frac{n(n-5)(n-4)}{6}
$$
possibilities.

Comment: Perhaps the Question is meant to treat rotated positions as equivalent; "arranged in a circle" otherwise has no import.  The consequence is to remove a factor of $n$ in the counting, as the first choice may be considered fixed.

Comment: @hardmath: I don't think that rotated positions count as equivalent, since the objects are "distinct". Still the circular arrangement has an impact: Every object has exactly two neighbors. If you arrange the objects in a row instead, you have two end positions which have only one neighbor.

Comment: Nice solution......azimut..