# Ten people standing in circle.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve the question:

> Ten people are standing are standing in a circle. Find the number of ways to choose $3$ people such that no $2$ of them are consecutive.

I have got the answer to be ${10\choose1}{6\choose2}$, but I'm not sure if this is right.

Please tell me if my answer is correct! If it's not, then where did I go wrong?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568045/combinatorics-circular-arrangement-problem

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose person one arbitrarily.
Then person two can have 10 - 3 positions. HOWEVER,

CASE 1:

If person two is 2 people away from person one, then they share an 'illegal' position. (namely the one that would give three consecutive people). Clearly, this can only happen for two of the positions of person two. (draw a picture). In this case person three can take one of five remaining positions. Thus; $10 \times 2 \times 5 = 100$

CASE 2:

If person two is more than 2 people away from person 1, then they don't share an illegal position. Person two may take one of five positions. And person three can take one of 4 positions. (draw another picture), giving $10 \times 5 \times 4 = 200$

The total number is then 300.