# Selecting 3 non-consecutive days of the week

Tags: combinatorics

We need to find how many groups of $3$ days of the week there can be, given that no two days should be consecutive. The answer should be $7$, but I do not know how to get to the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also assume that there cannot be consecutive days across two adjacent weeks. (If not, there are 10 possibilities.)

Comment: @mlc Certainly not a duplicate, since this special case has a simpler solution.

Comment: @user49640: in a comment to an answer, OP writes "I want to know the method to solve this problem because I will be applying it to bigger numbers." The general case covers that.

Comment: I agree. This question as stated seems much simpler than the linked question, but OP has made it very clear that the _purpose_ of the question is the same as that of the other question, namely, to get a general algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should weigh in on whether that previous Question is a duplicate.  It seems to me to demand, at the least, a clarification of the present Question if it is not to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: The solution in the link was exactly what I was looking for, so the question should be tagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The general formula for the number of circular arrangements of $k$ elements over $n$ spots with no consecutive elements is 
$$\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$$
See [Selection in Circular Table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566889/selection-in-circular-table/566929#566929) for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1010100 to represent that you 'pick' the first, third, and fifth day of the week. What ways are there to pick three non-consecutive days?

$1010100$

$1010010$

$1001010$

$0101001$

$0100101$

$0010101$

$0101010$

And that's it.

It turns out to be equal to the number of days in the week since as you can see there is one time where you have two days that you don't pick (the two 0's), and that 00 bit can start at any of the 7 days, fixing the rest of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have been more obvious in my question. I want to know the method to solve this problem because I will be applying it to bigger numbers. Trying every single possibility won't do when you are dealing with hundreds.

Comment: @Zweistein So can you post your more general question? Also, does the explanation about the 00 maybe help for your more general question?

Comment: @Bram28 Although your explanation is perfect for this one, it won't do for selecting 4 months of the year, for example.

Comment: @mlc But sunday and monday are consecutive.

Comment: @mlc It loops around, so the first and seventh are considered consecutive days.

Comment: @Zweistein OK, so you want a general formula of picking $k$ non-consecutive elements out of a circle of $n$?

Comment: Yup, exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a recurrence relation to solve this question. Let $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ be an n element set and let $f(n,k)$ be the number of $k$ element subsets with no two elements consecutive where we identify $1$ and $n$ as consectuive. In our case we are looking for $f(7,3)$. Note that
$$
f(n,k)=f(n-3,k-1)+f(n-1,k)\;\;\;\;\;\;\; n\geq 3
$$
by classifying such subsets which contain $1$ (and hence can't contain 2, and $n$) and such subsets which don't contain $1$. The initial conditions are $f(n,0)=1$. From here compute.

Answer (score 0):

For each day of the week $X$, there is exactly one way to select an arrangement so that $X$ is not one of the three days nor one of the three days immediately following them. So there are exactly seven possible arrangements, one for each choice of $X$.